# How to get the value of the counter of an AutoField?

Tags: django, django-models

How to get the value of the counter of an `AutoField`, such as the usual `id` field of most models?

At the moment, I do:

```
MyModel.objects.latest('id').id
```

But that does not work when all the objects have been deleted from the database.

Of course, a database-agnostic answer would be best.

**EDIT**

The accepted answer in [Model next available primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579957/model-next-available-primary-key) is not very relevant to my question, as I do not intend to use the counter value to create a new object. Also I don't mind if the value I get is not super accurate.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: This is to display on a status page to help me determine when I will need to switch to bingint for primary keys. Therefore, I need the information without creating an object.

Comment: That's not really something you need an exact value for. Take the latest and check to see if it's within a threshold.

Comment: That's what I did, until I happened to have a model for which the table is sometimes empty, as objects have a very short life time.

Comment: There is a great answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579957/model-next-available-primary-key) explaining why you probably don't want to do this - especially if objects have a short lifetime.

Comment: @solarissmoke See my edit. Can you develop on "especially if objects have a short lifetime"? Why does it matter?

Comment: It matters if you want an exact ID, which you don't, so my point is not relevant.

Comment: Why do you want this? This is raising all kinds of red flags. Don't use the auto generated field for anything other than letting the database use it for as unique identifier. If you need a field that you will manage, create a separate field. Don't use the default `id` field for other things. This will cause you many troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Background.

AFAIK there isn't a database agnostic query. Different databases handle auto increment differently and there rarely is a use case for django to find out what the next possible auto increment ID is.

To elaborate further, in postgresql you could do `select nextval('my_sequence')` while in mysql you would need to use the last_insert_id() but what this returns is the ID for the last insert and not the next one these two may actually be very different! To get the actual value you would need to use 'SHOW TABLE STATUS'

### Solution.

Create a record, save it, inspect it's ID and delete it.
This will change the next id but you have indicated that you need only an approximation.

The alternative is to do a manual transaction with a rollback. This too would alter the next id in case of mysql.

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def find_next_val(mymodel):
    try:
        # ...
        obj = mymoel.objects.create(....)
        print obj.id
        raise IntegrityError
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```